# Why is Qe2 stronger in this position?

Tags: strategy

I just finished reading Logical Chess Move by Move (should have read it before) and I just started with the Classic *My System*. I'm still on the beginners' part that talks about the center (can't wait to get to the positional chapter) and Nimzowitsch posts a game in which he says Qe2 is stronger. Here is the game.

```
 [FEN ""]
 1.e4 e5 2.f4 d5 3.exd5 Qxd5 4.Nc3 Qe6 5.fxe5 Qxe5 6.Be2
```

Nimzowitsch says that in the arising position Qe2 is stronger, why? Because we would have a development advantage of one piece? That doesn't look too of an advantage to me? (Note that Qe2 is referring to white's 6th move.)

Answer (score 8):

`Be2` makes no threat, leaves `g2` undefended, and seals in the Queen.  Black has `Bg4` which prevents `6... Bg4 7.Nf3 Bxf3 8.gxf3` as this leaves White with crummy pawns.

Black also has `Be7` followed by `Bh4`, exploiting White's weak black Kingside squares.

Finally, Black also can move either Knight. Black simply has no problems.

Comment: Thanks for helping out with the answer and with the diagram, I still dont get how to do it lol.

Comment: @AntonioAguilar the diagrams are fiddly. In your browser, do a "view source" on this page, search for FEN (or scroll down a ways), and you'll see one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Nimzowitsch wanted to demonstrate that after `6. Qe2`, if black exchanges the queens with `6... Qxe2+`, he will have **no development** because the only piece that was developed was the queen.

That is good for white since his advantage (the *difference* between black and white) in development has grown bigger.

If black doesn't exchange queens, he will have to protect his lady (for example with `6... Nc6`), but then white is winning more time anyway with `7. Nf3`.

---

I understand that `6. Be2` is more natural, because you want to keep queens on the board for an attack on the undeveloped black's army.

It's not that easy, thought, mainly because of the unpleasant move `6... Bg4`.